# What are the "gotchas" with ASP.NET MVC versus ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've recently walked through the entire NerdDinner pdf and sample with the final ASP.NEt MVC build and am thoroughly impressed. Before I start touting it's awesomeness through within our dev group, I'd like to also know what some of the pitfalls or misuses of this new stack. Can I possibly get an outline or explanation of when not to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Using controls built for ASP.Net webforms with MVC can be either very tricky or even impossible, depending on the control.